# Create a hierarchy for values in one column

Tags: hierarchy, spotfire

I have a column with a series of value like= JAN-18, FEB-18, MAR-18, ...  , Q-1-18,...Q-4-18, Y-18, Y-19 etc...  I need to create a Hierarchy on Spotfire which allows users to visualize details for marked values:

Suppose I have a graph with 3 lines, each for Y-18, Y-19, Y-20.

I would like to be able to choose an Year and drill down for quarters and months. Ex: An user interested in Y-18 should be able to see Q-1-18, Q-2-18, Q-3-18, Q-4-18 data by clicking on year curve.

I thought a hierarchy would have been the best way to do this but  what I see while inserting it is only columns, without the possibility to specify parameter for each column and I have only one column called "ProductType" for all this data.

EDITED: As requested 
[I've alleged an XLSX file with data and example graph](http://www.filedropper.com/desiderata)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly.  Can you give an example of a few rows from your data table?  (Depending on your columns, this might be a hierarchy thing, this might be a Dropdownlist/IronPython thing, or it might be something else entirely)

Comment: I edited my previous post with data requested

Comment: I'm apparently not going to remember to download this file when I'm on a computer that's allowed to.  I recommend posting a screenshot; otherwise, someone else can respond, or I'll take a look at it... eventually.

Comment: no thanks; I don't think I'll download a random xlsx :) could you please post an image or maybe just copy and paste some rows into an edit?